# Rspec assert that two sql queries are the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using rpsec to assert that a certain method generates the expected query:

```
describe '.customers' do

    let(:segment) { create(:segment) }
    
    let!(:rule1) do
      Rule.create!(segment: segment, filter_key: 'generic',
                   attr_name: 'first_name', operator: '=', values: ['john'])
    end
    
    let!(:rule2) do
      Rule.create!(segment: segment, filter_key: 'generic',
                   attr_name: 'orders_count', operator: '>=', values: ['3'])
    end
    
    let(:actual_query) { segment.customers.to_sql }
    let(:expected_query) do
      Customer
        .where('first_name = john')
        .where('orders_count >= 3')
        .to_sql
    end
    
    it 'applies all the rules scopes to customer' do
      expect(actual_query).to eq(expected_query)
    end

end
```

It usually passes, the thing is that sometimes (for some reason) the `where` clauses in one of the sql queries get reordered so, since the `to_sql` is actually the string of the query to execute, sometimes it fails saying:

> Failure/Error: expect(actual_query).to eq(expected_query)
>
> ```
>  expected: "SELECT \"customers\".* FROM \"customers\" WHERE (orders_count >= '3') AND (first_name = 'john')"
>
>     got: "SELECT \"customers\".* FROM \"customers\" WHERE (first_name = 'john') AND (orders_count >= '3')"
>  (compared using ==)
> ```

when they are actually the same in terms of the execution.
**Any ideas on how else to assert the two queries are the same without having to add test customers to compare the queries after they executed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that it is related to ordering of your rules in `segment.customers`. As they are created one just after another, it's possible that their timestamps in `created_at` are the same.

I would order them explicitly and add data that supports it in the spec, e.g.:

```
let!(:rule1) do
  Rule.create!(segment: segment, filter_key: 'generic',
               attr_name: 'first_name', operator: '=', values: ['john'],
               created_at: 2.days.ago)
end

let!(:rule2) do
  Rule.create!(segment: segment, filter_key: 'generic',
               attr_name: 'orders_count', operator: '>=', values: ['3'],
               created_at: 1.day.ago)
end
```

Comment: What if when I create the query I just concat the rules using `rules.order(:id).each do ...`. would that be enough? (asking because it's hard to test since error appears rarely)

Comment: That should be enough, if your database assign ids monotonically, i.e. next id is bigger than the previous one.

Comment: Awesome. I will make sure to run it a couple times before marking as answer thank you!